# Embedding HTML5 controls in Canvas?

Tags: html, canvas

I am developing a web UI that is so rich and sophisticated that it can only really be implemented entirely within an HTML5 Canvas control.  However, there are some "standard" HTML controls that I would like to somehow embed within the UI being rendered within the Canvas.

For example, I would like to be able to embed Google Maps within the Canvas.  Conceivably there will be many other controls types which I would also like to embed.

Is such embedding at all possible?  I am new to HTML5 so I am not sure if there is perhaps some way of rendering a standard control to an off-screen buffer and then blasting that buffer into the Canvas as an image.

Is any of this possible?

Thanks,

Felix

Answer (score 2):

A much easier solution than rendering your HTML off screen is to simply display some HTML in a div **over** the canvas.

I do that for all types of UI, especially inputs, without any problem. Just give a fixed position and a z-index to the HTML elements you want to display over the canvas, and append them to the DOM when you want them to be visible.

Comment: What about if I want to render a standard HTML control on the surface of a sphere in a 3D Canvas?  Is that possible?

Comment: With a native component ? I don't see how. If the component is in an iframe, depending on the CORS headers, you might even been unable to see what's inside from your script.

Answer (score 0):

Try google canvas control library these search words and see if that library fits your needs instead of doing a lot of rework.